# Completely remove duplicates from multidimensional array php

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array

```
[
    {
        "co": "INS-00002",
        "frequency": "ANNUAL",
        "line_No" : 345589
        "region": "REG-0006"
    },
    {
        "co": "INS-00002",
        "frequency": "MONTHLY",
        "line_No" : 345590
        "region": "REG-0003"
    },
    {
        "co": "INS-00002",
        "frequency": "MONTHLY",
        "line_No" : 345578
        "region": "REG-0002"
    },
    {
        "co": "INS-00002",
        "frequency": "ANNUAL",
        "line_No" : 345589
        "region": "REG-0006"
    },

]
```

The new output array i want should not include any duplicate values from the previous array. It should look like below sample

```
[
   {
        "co": "INS-00002",
        "frequency": "MONTHLY",
        "line_No" : 345590
        "region": "REG-0003"
    },
    {
        "co": "INS-00002",
        "frequency": "MONTHLY",
        "line_No" : 345578
        "region": "REG-0002"
    },
]
```

Comment: Please go read [ask]. This is not a code-writing service, you are supposed to show us what _you_ already did to try and solve the problem first of all.

Comment: And also, this lacks a proper explanation of what exactly is considered a “duplicate” here.

Comment: Ok. i have tried using  array_map("unserialize", array_unique(array_map("serialize", $my_data))). it works but i do not want any duplicate value present in the first array to appear in the second new array

Comment: I have no idea what you mean by that. You still need to properly _explain_ what exactly you consider a duplicate. With the approach you have just shown, it could only mean a duplicate has the exact same values for all four properties. But that doesn’t appear to make much sense, when put together with the rest of what you are saying.

Comment: the first array has 4 objects with line_No's [345589,345590,345578,345589], the second array has only 2 objects with line_No's [,345590,345578]. The duplicate line_No 345589 is not present in the second array

Comment: Ah, so you do not want to remove just the items that would be duplicates of another one that does get _kept_ in the result, but you want to remove _all_ items with a line no that occurs more than once. Then I’d start with `array_column` to extract the line no values, and `array_count_values` to figure out which occur more than once. Proceed from there by making use of that result in either `array_filter`, or with a simple foreach loop over the input array.

Comment: Thank you.. let me implement this

Answer (score 0):

You can make an empty array and compare each new item to all the existing items within it, if they did not match add the item to the new array.

```
$newArray = array();


foreach ($oldArray as $item)
{
    $duplicate = false;

    foreach ($newArray as $newItem)
    {
        if ($item == $newItem)
        {
            $duplicate = true;
            break;
        }
    }
    
    if (!$duplicate)
    {
        array_push($newArray, $item);
    }
}

print_r($newArray);
```

Answer (score 0):

`array_colum` to extract the line_Nos, `array_count_values` to count them, `array_filter` to filter those items from the input array, whose line_No has an occurrence count of 1.

```
$input = json_decode('[{"co":"INS-00002","frequency":"ANNUAL","line_No":345589,"region":"REG-0006"},{"co":"INS-00002","frequency":"MONTHLY","line_No":345590,"region":"REG-0003"},{"co":"INS-00002","frequency":"MONTHLY","line_No":345578,"region":"REG-0002"},{"co":"INS-00002","frequency":"ANNUAL","line_No":345589,"region":"REG-0006"}]');

// get all line_No values into array
$line_nos = array_column($input, 'line_No');
// count the number of time those values occur
$line_no_occurrences = array_count_values($line_nos);

// filter input array, take only those items whose line_No occurs with a count of 1
$result = array_filter($input, function($item) use($line_no_occurrences) {
  return $line_no_occurrences[$item->line_No] == 1;
});

var_dump($result);
```

Output:

```
array (size=2)
  1 => 
    object(stdClass)[2]
      public 'co' => string 'INS-00002' (length=9)
      public 'frequency' => string 'MONTHLY' (length=7)
      public 'line_No' => int 345590
      public 'region' => string 'REG-0003' (length=8)
  2 => 
    object(stdClass)[3]
      public 'co' => string 'INS-00002' (length=9)
      public 'frequency' => string 'MONTHLY' (length=7)
      public 'line_No' => int 345578
      public 'region' => string 'REG-0002' (length=8)
```